# 'iotedge check' - why would hostname need to start with the machine name

Tags: azure-iot-edge

if I run iotedge check, I get an error saying

"**Hostname in config.yaml must either be identical to the device hostname or be a fully-qualified domain name that has the device hostname as the first component.**

This is not true, of course, as I can use any FQDN I want providing that it matches *exactly* the name that my downstream clients use..  for example, I have an edge VM with this config (not my real names, but representative):
- the actual machine name is ubuntu1
- the 'hostname' in config.yaml is 'myedgebox.contoso.com'

this works fine as long as my leaf devices connect via myedgebox.contoso.com.

I can even use an IP address as my 'hostname', as long as that's what my leaf devices use in gatewayhostname...  :-)

Why the warning that my config hostname has to start with my machine name?  The two aren't related.  Is there some under the covers detail or best practice that I'm missing?

Comment: What's the use case for using a different hostname from leaf devices and going thru the trouble of making the required changes at the networking layer to route things correctly?

Comment: the main one for me is hosting my edge VM in Azure :-).   But I've seen instances where customers register a different DNS name than the device name (mostly to prevent actual machine name leakage, for security)